# Find the users which have not responded in the last 3 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the following PostgreSQL query

```
select unh.action_taken action_taken, un.user_id user_id 
from user_notification_history unh 
join user_notification un
on (unh.user_notification_id = un.id)
where unh.created_at between now() - interval '3 day' and now()
order by user_id asc
```

I get the following rows as a response

```
| action_taken | user_id |
| ------------ | ------- |
| done         | 1       |
| [null]       | 1       |
| [null]       | 1       |
| [null]       | 2       |
| [null]       | 2       |
| [null]       | 2       |
| [null]       | 3       |
| [null]       | 3       |
| [null]       | 3       |
| done         | 4       |
| [null]       | 4       |
| done         | 4       |
```

I want user_id, where the action_taken, is only [null] for the last 3 days, something like this

```
| action_taken | user_id |
| ------------ | ------- |
| [null]       | 2       |
| [null]       | 3       |
```

Comment: Hi ritikesh, also share the table schema or create SQL fiddle and share it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. (I.e. include both sample table data and the expected result.)

Answer (score 0):

try like below using not exists with your query

```
select distinct unh.action_taken action_taken, un.user_id user_id 
from user_notification_history unh 
join user_notification un
on (unh.user_notification_id = un.id)
where unh.created_at between now() - interval '3 day' and now()
and not exists (select 1 from user_notification_history a
     where a.user_id=unh.user_id
      and a.action_taken='done')
order by user_id asc
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it gives an error